# Azure Notification Hub: APNS dictionary not being sent.

Tags: ios, azure

I am relatively new to Azure notification hub. I have the system working when I send a JSON object formed like this.

```
{"aps": {"alert" : "hello"}}
```

But when I send the payload like below, Azure shows success in its debug console but it never gets to my mobile device.

```
{"aps": {"alert" : {"msg":"hello"}}}
```

The difference is clearly a string vs. an object. [APNS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) shows that I should be able to send a string or a dictionary.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Anyway to fix it? I would really like to be able to send an object rather than to have to parse the string on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my own answer. Very dumb of me not to read the documentation more carefully. The problem is the dictionary requires certain keys. The following payload will work.

```
{"aps": {"alert" : {"body":"hello"}}}
```

[image]

I missed that the dictionary requires certain keys. The docs specify that body, action-loc-key, loc-key, loc-args, launch-image. Here is a screen shot of the docs.

[image]